# Regular Expression for consecutive patterns

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
a aa aaa aaa aaaa aa aaa
```

And i need to catch all the `aaa` sequences in the text, but ignore them if there is four in a row, like `aaaa`. In the ideal case, I would be able to detect this:

```
a aa **aaa**  **aaa** aaaa aa **aaa**
```

Currently I have this regular expression:

```
[^a]aaa[^a]
```

This works well with the first and the last sequence 'aaa', but it can't catch the second one, since the space between `aaa aaa` belongs to the first pattern.

```
a aa **aaa**  aaa aaaa aa **aaa**
```

Any ideas on how to make this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you also want to catch the aaa if it's part of a sequence outside of spaces, e.g.

```
aaabbccaabccaccbbbaaaccbbaaaaccbbaacccaaab
^^^               ^^^                 ^^^
```

In this case, a negative lookaround would be your best bet:

```
re.findall('(?<!a)aaa(?!a)', mystring)
```

`(?<!a)` means "not preceded by an `a`".

`aaa` matches your three `a`s.

`(?!a)` means "not followed by an `a`".

Thus, the above only matches `aaa` without any additional `a`s directly before or after the matching three.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
\ba{3}\b
```

- Here `\b` means word boundaries.
- `a{3}` means match `a` exactly times
- `\ba{3}\b` means match 3 a's that are surrounded by word boundaries hence `aaaa` or `aaab` won't be matched.

Comment: yup, a description would be nice but this is the answer.  Please feel free to use this [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KGOFqt71Sx-EO4_5)